# How do you import the plone.importexport add-on correctly in plone?

Tags: plone, add-on

i am trying to install the add-on: plone.importexport, but i found this error:

```
user@wppi94:~/Plone/zinstance$ bin/buildout
Unused options for buildout: 'deprecation-warnings'.
Installing instance.
Couldn't find index page for 'plone.importexport' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'plone.importexport'.
Couldn't find index page for 'plone.importexport' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'plone.importexport'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'plone.importexport'.
```

Inside the buildout.cfg eggs I wrote this:

```
eggs =
    plone.importexport
    collective.easyform
    Plone
```

I managed to install the collective.easyform component, but I couldn't install this plone.importexport, can you tell me why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I have to use mr.developer to search in github. Watch this:
https://community.plone.org/t/how-do-i-install-the-plone-importexport-add-on/13698